I want add item to listbox to class to another form at first time it works perfectly but next time I get "Object not set to an instance of an object"
 public ClsLogs(Form frmmain) 
 {
     _frmmain = frmmain;
 }

 public void Logs(string ex)
 {
     ListBox ls = _frmmain.Controls["listbox1"] as ListBox;

     if (ls != null) 
         ls.Items.Add("Log->" + ex);
 }

I don't have any idea about it; I think my path is not true; but I try it:
ListBox ls = null;
ls = _frmmain.Controls["listbox1"] as ListBox;

if (ls != null) 
    ls.Items.Add("Log->" + ex);


Does this answer your question? What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?
